# PHPUnit Doctrine Repository magic methods

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, tdd

I need some help to fully test my class that depends on Doctrine.

I have one method in my class that uses that *magic* method *findOneBy...* from the Doctrine *EntityRepository*, as showed below:

[image]

But when I run my test I always have this warning:

[image]

How can I mock that call? Below I put how *EntityManager* magic __call method supposed to work:

[image]

Comment: what is the name of your field or can you show your entity?

Comment: setMethods can be used to add methods to a mocked object.  https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: The name of the field is $idShopUrl, in the run-code its fine, nothing is broken but I would like to know how to mock/test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock magic method `__call` which is invoked when invoking unacessible methods.

```
$mock
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('__call')
   ->with(
      $this->equalTo('findOneByIdShopUrl'), //
      $this->equalTo(['5'])
   )
   ->willReturn(['shop' => 'shop info']); // return shop object
```

Check also http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

The other option is to use `setMethods()`

```
$this->getMockBuilder('ShopRepository')->setMethods(['findOneByShopId'])->getMock();
```

and then the rest logic with methods like will, with etc.

Comment: setMethods is deprecated. The intended functionality is now provided by addMethods: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3687

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can replace the magic method findOneByXXXX('identifier') with the real method findOneBy(array('XXXX' => 'identifier')).

That is to say:

```
$this->shopUrlRepository->findOneByIdShopUrl($this->shop->getId());
```

To:

```
$this->shopUrlRepository->findOneBy(array('IdShopUrl' => $this->shop->getId()));
```

That is a real method. [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Both cases are valid but what is important for me in that scenario is the knowledge of how to mock it :)